# how multiply matrices and add them?

Tags: r, svm

I ask my question step by step, I would greatly appreciate if someone help me out.

input:

1-I have 2 vectors y and alpha with length 3000.

2- I have 2 matrixes xtrain with dim 3000*8 and and xtest with dim 5000*8

I want to do this:

I need the vector D, with length 5000 as a out put of the following calculation.

```
     D[j]=sum{i=1 to 3000} y[i]*alpha[i]* exp(sum{k=1 to 8}(xtrain[i,k]-xtest[j,k] )^2)
```

If the formula is not clear I can explain it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly simpler (and faster) version of @jogo's solution would be

```
D <- apply(xtest,                                        #work through xtest
           1,                                            #by row
           function(xtestj) {                            #apply this to each row
                   sum(y * alpha * 
                       exp(colSums((t(xtrain) - xtestj) ^ 2)))}
           )
```

By transposing `xtrain` in the formula, it takes advantage of `R`s recycling of vectors, so you don't need to set up a matrix of `xtestj` rows.  `rowSums` changes to `colSums` accordingly.

Comment: Eventually one can gain a little more speed with `txtrain <- t(xtrain); ... colSums((txtrain - xtestj)^2) ...`

Comment: Error: unexpected '}' in:
"             sum(y[1:5000] * solT1 * 
                   exp(colSums((t(train) - testj) ^ 2)))}"

Comment: It looks like you've lost the first { somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
D <- apply(xtest, 1, function(xtestj) sum(y*alpha*exp(rowSums(
    (xtrain-matrix(xtestj, nrow(xtrain), ncol(xtrain), byrow=TRUE))^2))))
```